# "Illegal break statement" is appearing. Can anyone suggest the reason to solve it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

"Illegal break statement" is appearing. Can anyone suggest the reason to solve it

```
this.selectOrganization = function() {

        organizationLocator.each(function(element) {

            FunctionLibrary.getText(element, organizationName).then(function(text) {
                logger.info(text);
                if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg')) {

                    FunctionLibrary.click(element, organizationName);

                    break;

                }
            })

        })
    };
```

Comment: `break`s should be inside loops (`for`, `while` and `do-while`)

Comment: Have you tried `return false`? Technically the loop code runs under the `each` function, and your code shown is a promise/callback.

Comment: Have you looked at using Array.every?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I just forgot that it can only be liked with loops. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
organizationLocator.each(function(element) {

            FunctionLibrary.getText(element, organizationName).then(function(text) {
                logger.info(text);
                if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg') && temp == true) {

                    FunctionLibrary.click(element, organizationName);

                    temp = false;



                }
            })

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't break from the `each` method—it emulates the native `forEach` method's behavior, and the native `forEach` doesn't provide to break the loop other than throwing an exception.

See the quote from [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> - A simple loop
> - A for...of loop
> - Array.prototype.every()
> - Array.prototype.some()
> - Array.prototype.find()
> - Array.prototype.findIndex()
>
> The other Array methods: every(), some(), find(), and findIndex() test the array elements with a predicate **returning a truthy value to determine if further iteration is required**.

But there is a solution of it which is[`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method, which uses it's callback's return value to iterate over next element.

> `every` executes the provided `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where `callback` returns a false value. If such an element is found, the `every` method immediately returns false.

Example of `Array.every` method:

```js
var orgs = ['NSO', 'CRY India', 'WHO', 'ImageResizingOrg', 'Unicef'];
var returnval = true;
orgs.every(function (text) {
    if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg')) {
        //you can do anything here like firing click event as you have done in your code
        returnval = false;
    }
    console.log(text);
    return returnval;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to combine each iteration of the for each loop and reject the promise when you wish to break out of the loop.

```
var promises = [];

organizationLocator.each(function(element) {
    promises.push(FunctionLibrary.getText(element, organizationName).then(function(text) {
        logger.info(text);
        if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg')) {
            FunctionLibrary.click(element, organizationName);
            return Promise.reject(false);
        }
    }));
});

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: can you look into this